# SVM Feature Selection in R

Tags: r, svm, libsvm, feature-selection

I am training a SVM classifier. Right now, I have about 4000 features, but a lot of them are redundant/uninformative. I want to reduce the features in the model to about maybe 20-50. I would like to use greedy hill climbing, reducing the features by 1 each time.
The removed feature should be the least important feature. After training an SVM, how do I get the ranking of the importance of the features? If I am using libsvm in R, how do I get the weight of each feature, or some other similar type of indicator of importance? Thanks!

Comment: This question [Variable Importance from SVM](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2179) from CrossValidated answers related question.

Comment: specifically, if I am using libsvm in the e1071 R package, how do I get the weight of each attribute? Thanks!

Comment: See also my [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150707)

Answer (score 3):

I would reduce the dimensionality of the problem first using PCA (Principal Component Analysis), then apply SVM. See, e.g., [Andrew Ng's lecture videos](https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/index)