# How to do feature selection using linear SVM weights

Tags: r, svm, feature-selection

I have built a SVM linear model for two types of classes (1 and 0), using the following code:

```
class1.svm.model <- svm(Class ~ ., data = training,cost=1,cross=10, metric="ROC",type="C-classification",kernel="linear",na.action=na.omit,probability = TRUE)
```

and I have extracted the weights for the training set using the following code:

```
#extract the weights and constant from the SVM model:

w <- t(class1.svm.model$coefs) %*% class1.svm.model$SV;  
b <- -1 * class1.svm.model$rho; #(sometimes called w0)
```

I get weights for each feature like the following example:

```
X2  0.001710949
X3  -0.002717934
X4  -0.001118897
X5  0.009280056
X993    -0.000256577
X1118   0
X1452   0.004280963
X2673   0.002971335
X4013   -0.004369505
```

Now how do I perform feature selection based on the weights extracted for each feature? how shall I build a weight matrix?

I read papers but the concept is yet not clear to me, Please help!

Comment: you can choose feature with max weight and run the model again on those feature. I am not sure though how it will work out. I would suggest you to use techniques like correlation, pca etc. In python algo like random forest  have attribute **feature importance**. I am not sure if it is available in R.

Comment: Yes I agree I need to choose max weight to build a model, but wanted to know what should be the cutoff to select the maximum weights to build a model

Comment: There is no such hard quoted value. All you can do is take all the features and remove them one by one features with less importance. And stop where you get max accuracy(or whatever is your performance measure).

Comment: Thanks :) but I have some weights in negative and some in positive, does that means I should consider only the positives one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dashed this answer off rather quickly, so I expect there will be quite a few points that others can expand on, but as something to get you started...

There are a number of ways of doing this,  but the first thing to tackle is to convert the linear weights into a measure of how important each feature is to the classification.  This is a relatively simple three step process:

1. Normalise the input data such that each feature has mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1.
2. Train your model
3. Take the absolute value of the weights.  That is, if the weight is -0.57, take 0.57.

Optionally you can generate a more robust measure of feature importance by repeating the above several times on different sets of training data which you have created by randomly re-sampling your original training data.

Now that you have a way to determine how important each feature is to the classification, you can use this in a number of different ways to select which features to include in your final model.  I will give an example of Recursive Feature Elimination, since it is one of my favourites, but you may want to look into iterative feature selection, or noise perturbation.

So,  to perform recursive feature elimination:

1. Start by training a model on the entire set of features, and calculate it's feature importances.
2. Discard the feature with the smallest importance value, and re-train the model on the remaining features
3. Repeat 2 until you have a small enough set of features[1].

[1] where a small enough set of features is determined by the point at which the accuracy begins to suffer when you apply your model to a validation set.  On which note:  when doing this sort of method of feature selection, make sure that you have not only a separate training and test set, but also a validation set for use in choosing how many features to keep.